# How to use a load balancer with apache with php based applications?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, load-balancing, directory

I have found that i need to add another server to my setup but my web application is designed with php. Basically, in my application, there is a mkdir command that makes a directory for the user. If i have a load balancer then the load balancer might not send the request to the server that originally created the directory. What is a solution to this? I want to use haproxy and apache. I was thinking that there could be some way to assign a request to a specific server that they would be directed to every time they access the application.

Answer (score 2):

The "easiest" way is to have an additional server that acts as a file server. This way, both web servers can map the same directory and share the folder(s) required. Two file servers are recommended for redundancy purposes.

Comment: I thought about this, but what would i do when the file server reaches capacity? How could i make so that if i needed to, i could add space on the file server without effecting any information already on it?

Comment: Bigger disks? You'd really need to think about capacity planning.

Comment: or a distributed file system, like gluster.